# How to find average time points difference in longitudinal data

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data

I have longitudinal data of body weights of over 100K participants. Time points of weight measurements between participants are not the same. What I want to know is the average time difference between 1st and 2nd measurement as well as 2nd and 3rd measurement etc. Another one is how many people or % of people who have 3 body weight measurements, as well as for 4,5, 6, 7, and 8 etc. How can I do to find these answers on R.